# How to rotate a 3D model around its center?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I am making a 3d car game and I have a problem with rotation.
I want to rotate a model around itself but when I move, it starts to move around 
the world !

The question is: How do I make a center for the model to move around?

I tried to change the code like this :

```
 effect.World = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(modelRotation) *  effect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
```

now instead of moving forward relative to the model, orientation it moves in a set direction !
& this is my code:

```
 effect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(modelRotation); 
                effect.View = camera.View; 
                effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
```

Comment: I suggest you stick with a single assignment operator per statement.  If you don't, the result can be confusing, surprising, and hard to read.

Comment: What happened when you did this:  effect.World = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(modelRotation) *  effect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);  I'm confused, you said it 'moves in a set direction', what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3):

I have a few tips to get you started:

1. Matrix multiplication order in DirectX/Xna is differrent than you learned in school.

In school `v = A B y` meant: `v = A (B y)`. So when chaining matrices, B is applied first.

If you want to combine matrix A and B, you multiply them like `C = A B`

In Directx/XNA, the order is reversed. To combine matrix B and A, you write `var C = B * A;`

To stop me from making mistakes, I adopt a naming convention: each matrix (or transform) is called `AtoB`: `WorldToView`, `ModelToWorld`, or `ModelToRotatedModel`.

This reminds you that the output of the first matrix must match the input of the right matrix :

```
  var modelToView = modelToWorld * worldToView;
```

and not:

```
  var nowhereToNowhere = worldToView * modelToWorld;
```

This helped me a lot, I hope it helps you sort out your matrix problems.

P.S. 
I hope the origin of your car model is in the center of the car, otherwise the it will still move around strangely.

Comment: How to get the origin of the car?

Comment: @zionpi The easiest is computing the bounding box of the the car, and then take the center of this box.

Answer (score 3):

Try switching these values around:

`effect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(modelRotation);`

so it becomes:

`effect.World = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(modelRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);`

I follow a simple acronym thats called `ISROT`

> Identity
>
> Scale
>
> Rotation
>
> Orientation
>
> Translation

You work right to left, so you always end your statement with `Translation`.